# Why can't Nokogiri wrap my image with a link?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I'm confused about the reaction of Nokogiri (1.6.6.2), when I try to wrap an image with a link tag. Here is an example of my problem:

```
fragment = Nokogiri::HTML5.fragment("<p>Example</p><img src='test.jpg' class='test'><p>Example</p>")
```

Now I would like to wrap the image with a link:

```
fragment.search('img').wrap('<a href="http://www.google.com"></a>')
```

This unfortunately results in an error:

```
ArgumentError: Requires a Node, NodeSet or String argument, and cannot accept a NilClass.
(You probably want to select a node from the Document with at() or search(), or create a new Node via Node.new().)
```

Now the very strange this is, it works with other tags:

```
fragment.search('img').wrap('<something href="http://www.google.com"></something>')
```

Why is Nokogiri doing that? Is it a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is:

```
uninitialized constant Nokogiri::HTML5 (NameError)
```

You want `Nokogiri::HTML` instead.

Running this:

```
require 'nokogiri'

fragment = Nokogiri::HTML.fragment("<p>Example</p><img src='test.jpg' class='test'><p>Example</p>")
fragment.search('img').wrap('<a href="test">')
```

and looking at fragment afterwards:

```
puts fragment.to_html
# >> <p>Example</p><a href="test"><img src="test.jpg" class="test"></a><p>Example</p>
```

It appears to be working correctly. Adding the trailing `</a>` also works.

Perhaps you need to check your Nokogiri and libXML2 versions.

Comment: It actually works if I use `Nokogiri::HTML` instead of `Nokogiri::HTML5`. Thank you!